# Removing a hex code using preg/regex (curly brackets)

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm wondering, what would be a sufficient regex to do this:

BEFORE:

`{FFFFFF}Potatoes are{FF0000} Awesome`

AFTER:

`Potatoes are Awesome`

Looked around for something similar, had trouble editing one that used '[' instead of '{', so I'm asking how I could put preg_replace into use to yield the after result.

Thanks!

Comment: is the hex always FFFFFF or FF0000 ?

Comment: it is subject to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$re = "/(?i){[a-f0-9]+}/"; 
$str = "{FFFFFF}Potatoes are{FF0000} Awesome";  
$result = preg_replace($re, '', $str); // Potatoes are Awesome
```

#### [Online Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tN7uW1/1)

Comment: well comments tell me I can't thank you, but I definitely can say this works.

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: Short and sweet, +1 :) @Lorenc According to the iron laws of SO etiquette, I'm allowed to [tell someone who has never accepted an answer about how it works](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251288/). :) If this or another answer works, would you consider clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer to say you accepted it? That's how the reputation system works here, accepting an answer gives reputation both to the answerer and to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try below regex that match hex string enclosed inside `{...}` that is *either 3 or 6 characters long*. For eg: `#FFF` and `#FFFFFF` will produce the same result

```
{[0-9A-Fa-f]{3}}|{[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}}
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tN7uW1/9)

---

> had trouble editing one that used '[' instead of '{',

Use escape sequence `\` character to escape `[` and `]`.

```
\[[0-9A-Fa-f]{3}\]|\[[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}\]
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tN7uW1/11)

*Note:* Combine both regex pattern using OR `|` to match all the possible cases that is either enclosed in `{...}` or `[...]`